# Teutonic vs Norse Tag

Tags: discussion, tags

As the title says, should we have a `teutonic` tag or a `norse` tag, or perhaps `teutonic` as a synonym for `norse`?

Personally, I feel `teutonic` is the better choice but I'm aware that not many people will understand this to mean Norse/Scandinavian.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't "Teutonic mythology" generally refer to non-Scandinavian Germanic myth, as opposed to "Norse", which refers to Scandinavian myth?

Comment: It seems to be sketchily defined elsewhere (from what I could find) and often used interchangeably.

Comment: @StuartH I find that some people use them interchangeably, but I'm pretty sure they are different, but their mythology is very similar. Much like the greek-roman mythologies.

Comment: Related: [Greek, Roman, and Greco-Roman tags. Are these synonyms?](http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/q/117)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let them both exist for now.  In a few months when the volume has increased it the answer should be obvious.