# Greek, Roman, and Greco-Roman tags. Are these synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

We currently have [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek), [roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman), and [greco-roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greco-roman) tags. I'm not sure what to suggest as synonyms for what.

First, we all know that greek and roman mythology is so similar that "greco-roman" is a legitimate term in all academic circles, so perhaps greek and roman tags should be synonyms of a greco-roman tag.

But, there seems to be a convention developing where a good portion of tagging revolves around identifying the geographic location where a myth was prominent. For example, there is [pacific-northwest](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pacific-northwest), [chinese](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chinese), and [irish](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irish), all in use to identify that the question is about myths from those areas.

Further, there are plenty of instances where a question should have either a greek or roman tag, but not the other. (Greek examples: [1](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2/did-the-greeks-build-temples-for-all-of-the-children-of-cronus) [2](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/1/where-can-i-find-the-earliest-literary-compendium-for-the-greek-pantheon) [3](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/275/did-ancient-greek-religion-ever-become-monotheistic) Roman examples: [1](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/171/worship-of-epona-in-the-roman-empire) [2](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/216/how-does-the-genius-concept-fit-into-the-roman-mythology) [3](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/302/were-romulus-and-remus-real-people)).

So it seems like having a greek tag *and* a roman tag is a necessity.

The question now: Should we have a greco-roman tag, or should questions just use both greek and roman as needed and [greco-roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greco-roman) should be a synonym of both?

---

Similarly, [norse](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/norse) and [teutonic](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teutonic) are near synonyms, but they are different. [Reference a current meta post](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/teutonic-vs-norse-tag).

Answer (score 10):

I would say they should be separate tags.

Greek and Roman mythology have a great deal of similarity, but they are **not** identical. For example, I doubt anyone thinks [a question on Romulus and Remus](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/302/were-romulus-and-remus-real-people) can be legitimately tagged [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek). Therefore, [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) and [roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman) are obviously not synonyms.

(edited)
Neither of these should be synonyms for [greco-roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greco-roman). One possible use for this tag is for questions on the wider [Graeco-Roman world](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greco-Roman_world) of classical antiquity. I'm not sure if we have, or will get, many questions where this might be applicable though. In most cases tagging a question with both [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) and [roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman) is probably sufficient.

Comment: So you favor that if the question is equally about greek and roman things, then it should be tagged "greco-roman" not both "greek" and "roman"? We'll have to do a lot of editing, because people will be getting that wrong daily.

Comment: Someone created [tag:abrahamic-religions]. Different question, but what do you think should be done in relation to [tag:judeo-christian]?

Comment: @fredsbend I think we should focus on one question atm. Semaphore's answer is feasible. Right now we dont have enough [greco-roman] questions. So there will be some initial confusion. Once the tag has been used for a good amount of questions, the mis-tag will reduce. But newcomers will often make mistakes, so its perfectly fine.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin Have you looked through the greek tag questions? Many of them should probably be tagged greco-roman according to semaphore's answer here. There's already a mistagging problem. At least the tag wikis should be edited to tell how to use the tags.

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​I strongly agree that [greek] and [roman] shouldn't be synonymised, but disagree on keeping the [greco-roman] tag. I think plannapus' suggestion for using both tags for truly greco-roman questions would be preferable.

Answer (score 4):

My answer is more or less similar to Semaphore answer (i. e. [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) and [roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman) should be separate tags) with the distinction that I think questions on elements common to both greek and roman traditions should use [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek)[roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/roman) instead of [greco-roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greco-roman).

The reason being that if someone wants to follow questions on greek mythology, in the second case, that person would have to follow both tags [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) and [greco-roman](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greco-roman) to do so instead of just one single [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) tag. In the same way someone wanting to have a look at all questions involving greek mythology would have to query `[greek][greco-roman]` instead of just clicking on the [greek](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greek) tag.

Answer (score -1):

"Classical Mythology" might be the appropriate tag for the co-mingled Greek and Latin mythologies.

Comment: Yes, I like the idea, but that seems more regarding mythology as an element in literature, rather than an anthropological study.